# How to align Div at right side bottom?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am developing MVC4 application. I have one main div inside that I have three div tags. First two div tags are displaying correctly as per my requirement. However my third div tag appears in right middle. I want it in left bottom side. I tried all the ways.

```
<div id="dialog" class="doc-verification-outer">
    <div id="data" style="width:70%;height:inherit;float:left" class="doc-verification"></div>
    <div id="details" width="30%" style="float:right;height:50%; width:30%"></div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Reject Reason">
        <div style="height:200px;">
            <input type="hidden" value="_upload_id" id="id" />
            <br />
            <label for="name">Select your reason</label>
            <select id="comments">
                <option value="1">Incorrect Document</option>
                <option value="2">document is not clear</option>
                <option value="3">document is not valid</option>
                <option value="4">other document</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" id="reject" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons blue" value="Ok" onclick="reject();" tabindex="-1" style="float:right;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone give some insights regarding this? Thank you very much...

Comment: give clear:both css style property to third div. @Niranjan Godbole

Comment: Explain Clearly You want left bottom or right bottom

Comment: Right bottom. Clear:both working fine but it goes to full left bottom . I want it immediatly below details div

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```html
<div id="dialog" class="doc-verification-outer">
    <div id="data" style="width:70%;height:inherit;float:left" class="doc-verification"></div>
    <div id="details" width="30%" style="float:right;height:50%; width:30%"></div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Reject Reason">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" value="_upload_id" id="id" />
            <br />
            <label for="name">Select your reason</label>
            <select id="comments">
                <option value="1">Incorrect Document</option>
                <option value="2">document is not clear</option>
                <option value="3">document is not valid</option>
                <option value="4">other document</option>
            </select>
            
        </div>
      <div style="margin-top:5px;"><input type="button" id="reject" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons blue" value="Ok" onclick="reject();" tabindex="-1" style="margin-left:122px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to split the third div into two parts so the right part should align with your second div
Try this :

```
<div id="dialog" class="doc-verification-outer">
    <div id="data" style="width:70%;height:inherit;float:left" class="doc-verification">First DIV</div>
    <div id="details" width="30%" style="float:right;height:50%; width:30%">Second div</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Reject Reason">
        <div style="height:200px;">
            <div style="width:70%;display:inline-block">
            <input type="hidden" value="_upload_id" id="id" />
            <br />
            <label for="name">Select your reason</label>
            <select id="comments">
            <option value="1">Incorrect Document</option>
            <option value="2">document is not clear</option>
            <option value="3">document is not valid</option>
            <option value="4">other document</option>
        </select>
            </div>
            <div style="width:29%;display:inline-block">
                <input type="button" id="reject" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons blue" value="Ok" onclick="reject();" tabindex="-1" style="float:left;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. Yes but dropdown coming at left bottom and ok button at right bottom. I want to display both at right bottom.